# Trying to check for duplicates in Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

```
// This code lets the computer select the first random number from your array
int rn1 = boarduser[new Random().nextInt(boarduser.length)];
System.out.println("Computer's Value: " + rn1);

// This code lets the computer select the second random number from your array
int rn2 = boarduser[new Random().nextInt(boarduser.length)];
System.out.println("Computer's Value: "+ rn2);

boolean tokenduplicate1; // check if the computer took the same value twice

for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
    if (rn2 == rn1) {
    tokenduplicate1 = true;}
    while (tokenduplicate1);

    // This code lets the computer select the third random number from your array
    int rn3 = boarduser[new Random().nextInt(boarduser.length)];
    System.out.println("Computer's Value: "+ rn3);

    boolean tokenduplicate2; // check if the computer took the same value twice

    for (int k = 0; k < i; ++k) {
        if (rn3 == rn1 || rn3 == rn2) {
        tokenduplicate1 = true;}
        while (tokenduplicate1);
```

I want to start off by saying I have a limited knowledge of Java, so here it is

The code is still incomplete, but what I'm trying to do is check if the random variable selected in `boarduser` is the same as the previous value. If it is, I want it to choose another variable within my `boarduser` array until it is not the same as the previous one.

Comment: I think you should read some basic code tutorial, `while (tokenduplicate1);` looks at least odd

Comment: I know, it's not complete, it was my attempt at trying to create a loop that would choose another random int rn2 but it doesn't work

Comment: [Some reading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) if you want

Comment: If you want to eliminate duplicates, Java's Sets are a great idea, because their built-in functionality is to contain no duplicates. I posted an answer, that uses sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep (re)selecting a second value until it doesn't agree with the first one.

```
int rn1 = boarduser[new Random().nextInt(boarduser.length)];
System.out.println("Computer's Value: " + rn1);
int rn2 = boarduser[new Random().nextInt(boarduser.length)];
while(rn2 == rn1)
{
    rn2 = boarduser[new Random().nextInt(boarduser.length)];
}
System.out.println("Computer's Value: " + rn2);
```

Comment: NB: this could lead to an infinite loop if `boarduser` contains only equal values

Comment: Actually `boarduser`is generated so that there are no duplicate numbers!! So this really helped! Thank you!

Comment: if you have no duplicate, just shuffle the array and take the N first

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Set and then check for its length.

```
int somevalue = 3; // if you want 3 values

Set<Integer> numbers = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
while(numbers.size() != somevalue) {
    numbers.add(new Random().nextInt(boarduser.length));
}

System.out.println(numbers);
```

Prints for example: [11, 1, 5]